# File Splitting code in Java is not working as required

Tags: java, file-io

I have tried the following code for file splitting, it works but not as required.
i.e. an mp3 file names 'song.mp3' has  size of 2540KB, expected number of chunks (100KB each) are 25 but codes gives only 12 chunks, I don't understand the reason.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

              File file = new File("song.mp3");

    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("song.mp3");
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("song_0.mp3");
    int chunk_size = 1024 * 100;
    byte[] buff = new byte[chunk_size]; // 100KB file
    int i = 0;
    String file_name = file.getName();
    String file_name_base = file_name.substring(0, 
    file_name.lastIndexOf("."));
    while (fIn.read() != -1) {

        fIn.read(buff);
        int total_read = 0;
        total_read += chunk_size;
        long read_next_chunk = total_read;
        String file_name_new = file_name_base + "_" + i + ".mp3";
        File file_new = new File(file_name_base);
        i++;
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file_name_new);
        fOut.write(buff);

        fIn.skip(total_read);// skip the total read part

    } // end of while loop

    fIn.close();
    fOut.close();

}
```

Comment: do the chunks you do get represent the entire original file? do you get an Error somewhere? ... ?

Comment: `while (fIn.read() != -1)`  and then after that  `fIn.read(buff)`. Do you understand what you're doing?

Comment: Yes I know what I'm doing. I don't get any error from this code. fIn.read()  returns -1 if nothing left in input file to read. I wan to loop over reading the entire file until it ends. Am I doing something wrong? plz guide.

Comment: I want to emulate a cloud storage (BLOB) in which my App saves the large file in chunks of small size (50-100KB) and I keep the hash of each chunk at local for integrity check.

Comment: `fIn.read()`: **Reads a byte of data from this input stream**

Comment: @forpas `fIn.read(buff)` reads as many bytes as we want i.e. size of buff byte array.

Comment: `fIn.read()` without any parameter:  **Reads a byte of data from this input stream**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is sure that does not work, at least because: 
at each iteration you read 1 Byte and throw it away by `while (fIn.read() != -1)`.
Change your loop to something like this:

```
int bytesReadCounter;
while((bytesReadCounter = fIn.read(buff, 0, chunk_size)) > 0){
    .................................. 
    fOut.write(buff, 0, bytesReadCounter);
    ..................................
}
```

In `buff` you store the Bytes read and in `bytesReadCounter` the number of Bytes read. 
Then you write to `fOut` from `buff` exactly `bytesReadCounter` Bytes.

**Edit**, use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("song.mp3");

    FileInputStream fIn = null;
    try {
        fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int chunk_size = 1024 * 100;
    byte[] buff = new byte[chunk_size]; // 100KB file
    int i = 0;
    String file_name = file.getName();
    String file_name_base = file_name.substring(0, file_name.lastIndexOf("."));
    int bytesReadCounter;
    boolean hasMore = true;
    while (hasMore) {
        try {
            bytesReadCounter = fIn.read(buff, 0, chunk_size);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

        hasMore = bytesReadCounter > 0;

        if (!hasMore)
            break;

        String file_name_new = file_name_base + "_" + i + ".mp3";
        File file_new = new File(file_name_new);

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file_new);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

        try {
            fOut.write(buff, 0, bytesReadCounter);
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    try {
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are reading 1KB and writing 1KB to output file. I know something is wrong in loop condition to read 100KB in each iteration. one option is to read entire file into buffer and iterate over buffer to write it out using `skip()` method.

Comment: The above code reads `chunk_size` Bytes at each iteration without losing any. In the last iteration of course there may be less than `chunk_size` Bytes.

Comment: can I read a file through FileInputStream from a specified byte location?

Comment: Above code means mine. No you can't. You will have to read from the start until the point you want.

Comment: you rocks sir. Thank u so much for your kind help, I have not understood the full code yet but it works. I'll let you know I have any queries. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a question, FIS (fileinputstream) continue reading next bytes (chunk size) as far as FIS closes or file ends?

Comment: another question for you, why you are reading 100KB in buff and then 1KB again inside loop?

Comment: @SaqibAli that was a copy/paste error from my pc. I edited a few lines of my code.

Comment: thanks I have tested by commenting out extra lines, it now working ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to immediately propose the newer [`Path/Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) classes.

The following code is not tested, but has a clear buffered reading:

- read the original file sequentially
- loop the parts
- write a part using a buffer (`block`) - which is faster than a mere FileInputStream

So:

```
public static void splitFile(String file) throws IOException {
    final long partSize = 100 * 1024;

    Path originalPath = Paths.get(file);
    if (Files.isReadable(originalPath)) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Is not a readable file: " + originalPath);
    }
    // Read the file:
    long totalSizeToRead = Files.size(originalPath);
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(originalPath)) {
        int partNo = 0;
        byte[] block = new byte[16 * 1024];
        // Write parts
        while (totalSizeToRead > 0) {
            // Write part
            ++partNo;
            Path partPath = Paths.get(String.format("%s-%03d.part", file, partNo));
            int sizeToReadInPart = partSize;
            if (totalSizeToRead < sizeToReadInPart) {
                sizeToReadInPart = (int) totalSizeToRead;
            }
            try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(partPath,
                                    StandardOpenOptions.REPLACE_EXISTING)) {
                // Write blocks of part
                while (sizeToReadInPart > 0) {
                    int toRead = Math.min(block.length, sizeToReadInPart);
                    int actuallyRead = in.read(block, 0, toRead);
                    sizeToReadInPart -= actuallyRead;
                    if (actuallyRead <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    out.write(block, 0, actuallyRead);
                }
            }
            totalSizeToRead -= sizeToReadInPart;
        }
    }
}
```

The points here:

- try-with-resource automatically closes, even on return/break/thrown exception.
- I used the file size (a Long) and int for Buffer sizes, needs some care. Also it is a redundancy, given `actuallyRead`.
- Java by convention uses camelCase instead of underscores for normal variables.

Comment: thanks @Joop Eggen I'll definitely give a try to it, is it more efficient than mine computationally ?